# How to connect branch policies with work items in Azure Repos?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have a couple of questions about branch policies in Azure Repos.

As you can see we have a branching strategy based on linked items in Azure DevOps.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to allow users push their changes to **Main branch** only if their branch is connected with some story?
2. And the second -- is it possible to allow users push changes to **Story branch** only if their task is child to story in which they are trying to push?

I have read all docs about polices and have not found anything appropriate

Or what policies could you recommend if nothing exists from the above

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to allow users push their changes to Main branch only if their branch is connected with some story?

I am afraid there is no such setting or way to achieve this at this moment.

We could noly set the **Check for linked work items** in the branch policy:

[image]

However, it is not yet possible to make more detailed requirements for the work items associated with the requirements at this time.

> And the second -- is it possible to allow users push changes to Story
> branch only if their task is child to story in which they are trying
> to push?

Similar to your first question, there is no way to do additional requirements on associated work items.

**To resolve this issue**, we need to enable the option Check for linked work items and we could add the **Automatically included reviewers** to check type of connected workitems：

[image]